# Spring Integration Metadata store

Tags: spring, spring-integration, metadata, spring-jdbc, file-monitoring

As a novice in Spring Integration, I have been struggling to find a way to "read a file " and mark that particular file as **read** in order to avoid another concurrent application to read the same file (prevent duplicates).

Spring integration provides Metadata-store. How can I implement this solution with JDBC-Metadata-Store? Is there any example or tutorial to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

According the `JdbcMetadataStore` [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-metadata-store), you need to follow the link to the [Reading Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading) chapter. And there is a paragraph about a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`, which in conjuction with the `MetadataStorte` ensures a single file process per concurrent applications.

Comment: I could make it working where only one server is actually processing the file. I'm now struggling to stop a random Oracle primary key violation I see at the logs time to time. Any idea about what could be wrong or missing?

Comment: Please, raise a new SO thread with much more info: doesn't looks like this old one is relevant anymore. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747197/duplicatekeyexception-raised-when-using-spring-jdbcmetadatastore-oracle

Comment: Hi Artem, I just raised a new SO thread as requested. See link above. Thank you!